# Hiding the active Administrator account in Windows 8

Tags: user-management, users, user-accounts, user-permissions, windows-8.1

I am trying to use the integrated "Administrator" account in Windows 8. The problem is that I do not want this account to appear on the Welcome Screen for login. I tried to hide the account by using the method described [here](http://www.top-password.com/blog/hide-user-account-from-welcome-screen-in-windows-8-7-vista-xp/). The problem is that the other accounts are no admins and when they are trying to (un)install a program or basically Need admin rights, the `UAC prompts them to enter an administrator password. However, there are no possible accounts` listed (since it has been deactivated). (I have actually debarred myself from the Administrator account...)

**EDIT:**
Furthermore, I tried using `net user administrator /active:no`. This had the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found a solution. This question has already been asked on superuser.

For the solution see:
https://superuser.com/questions/182375/always-display-the-last-default-user-windows-7-welcome-screen/182382#182382
and
https://superuser.com/questions/66400/hide-account-from-login-screen-but-can-be-used-in-uac.

Answer (score 2):

If you did not disable the Administrator account, just hidden it from the login screen, you can log in as Administrator via Remote Desktop connection. (provided that remote desktop is enabled on the machine...)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using net user to disable the admin account?

```
net user administrator /active:no
```

> NOTE : open command prompt via Run it as administrator

Comment: I updated the question.